# Where is the best place to #include function definitions?

Tags: c, include, header-files

I am writing a rather large program in C and I had a question about header files. My main file includes my library header containing all of the function declarations. In the files that contain my function definitions, I have them include that same header file. When I compile, I link all the object files together.

It occurred to me that instead of having my definition files include the header file and then linking the results together, I could simply have the header file include the definitions at the END of the header file, like:

```
#ifndef HEADER
#def HEADER
#include <stdio.h>
#include <hdf.h>

... (function declarations)

#include "definition1.c"
#include "definition2.c"
#endif
```

What would be the benefits of doing it this way versus what I have now?

Comment: Ackk!!  `#include "foo.c"` is an anti-pattern.  Please don't do that.

Comment: Linking is the right way to go. Including C files in headers is the wrong way to go.

Comment: For the best flexibility, each source file should have its' own header file. Then each source file includes its' own header file AND the header file(s) for any external functions it calls.